# How to export global variable from browserify/babelify to be used in project without browserify?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

**Scenario:**

I have 2 projects with quite different setup:

1. Regular website, legacy code with simple gulp setup
2. Small pet project. JS slider plugin written with help of ES6 classes (transpiled with babel). JS gulp task:

   ```
   gulp.task('js', function() {
   return gulp.src('src/scripts/*.js')
   .pipe($.plumber())
   .pipe(through2.obj(function (file, enc, next) {
       browserify(file.path, { debug: true })
       .transform(require('babelify'))
       .transform(require('debowerify'))
       .bundle(function (err, res) {
           if (err) { return next(err); }
           file.contents = res;
           next(null, file);
       });
   }))
   .on('error', function (error) {
       console.log(error.stack);
       this.emit('end')
   })
   .pipe( $.rename('alder.js'))
   .pipe( gulp.dest('dist/scripts/'));
   ```

   });

**What I want to achieve?**

I'd like to be able to use the file outputed by browserify/babelify in this regular website (without setting up the whole browserify/babelify stuff).

**The question**

Of course browserify / babelify does some magic stuff and finally wraps the variable into function scope what hides this variable/constructor function. So the question is what is the correct way to export global variable / constructor function that can be used in other projects? At this point the only thing that comes to my mind is to attach my function to the window object like:

```
    class Alder { // constructor and then methods }
    export default Alder;
    window['Alder'] = Alder
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Set the `standalone` option:

> When `opts.standalone` is a non-empty string, a standalone module is created with that name and a [umd](https://github.com/forbeslindesay/umd) wrapper. You can use namespaces in the standalone global export using a `.` in the string name as a separator, for example `'A.B.C'`. The global export will be [sanitized and camel cased](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/umd#name-casing-and-characters).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Looks like this option actually attaches function to window object as well :)

Comment: Yep, but it also works in a CommonJS and other environments.